# page is going up on pressing tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function using jquery tabs. The function working fine. but when I press tab key the Page is moving up.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
     var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
     if (keyCode === 9) {
         if (!$('#appinfo:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('appinfo') != -1) {
             $('#ATab1').removeClass('active');
             $('#ATab2').addClass('active');

             $('#appinfo').hide();
             $('#loanprogram').show();
             $('#miworksheet').hide();
             window.location = '#loanprogram';
         }
         else if (!$('#loanprogram:last-child').is(':focus') && window.location.href.search('loanprogram') != -1) {
             $('#ATab2').removeClass('active');
             $('#ATab3').addClass('active');

             $('#appinfo').hide();
             $('#loanprogram').hide();
             $('#miworksheet').show();
             window.location = '#miworksheet';
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Add a jsfildde, please.

Comment: You might need to prevent the normal behaviour? Because the tab key also goes trough all elements on your website.

Comment: then what i have to change

Comment: To prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree add: e.stopPropagation(), to prevent the default action add: e.preventDefault()